# General dot product rule

Tags: linear-algebra

> I have a vector $v$ and a **scalar** $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

let $w = a\overrightarrow{v}$

> Then is $\overrightarrow{w} \cdot \overrightarrow{v} = a(\overrightarrow{v} \cdot \overrightarrow{v})$

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes;  the dot product is bilinear.